# jQuery using .text('&pound;') but it outputs that as a string, what am I doing wrong?

Tags: jquery

I'm using this:

```
$("td.amount_to_pay").text('&pound;' + response.new_total);
```

Yet £ is being printed on the screen, I've tried just £ but that outputs a character set issue kinda thing.

What can I do?

Thanks.

Comment: *"We need to be aware that this method escapes the string provided as necessary so that it will render correctly in HTML. To do so, it calls the DOM method .createTextNode(), which replaces special characters with their HTML entity equivalents (such as &lt; for <)."* Source: [The documentation](http://api.jquery.com/text/#text2)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try using the `.html()` method instead of `.text()` if you want to provide HTML unencoded value to be outputted as HTML. The `.text()` method always HTML encodes the values.

```
$("td.amount_to_pay").html('&pound;' + response.new_total);
```

Comment: `$("td.amount_to_pay").html('&pound;' + response.new_total);`

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
$("td.amount_to_pay").html('&pound;' + response.new_total);
```